# Is every topological space a right topological semigroup?

Tags: general-topology, semigroups

Recall that a triple $(X,\tau,\ast)$ is a right topological semigroup if for every $x,y,z\in X$ it stands that $(x\ast y)\ast z=x\ast(y\ast z)$ and for every $y\in X$ we have that the map $\ast_y:X\to X$ given by $\ast_y(x)=x\ast y$ is $\tau$-continuous.

It's known that given a set $X$ there exist a map $f:X^2\to X$ such that $(X,f)$ is a group, but is not truth that given a topological space $(X,\tau)$ exists a map $f:X^2\to X$ such that $(X,\tau,f)$ is a topological group, even if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

My question is: It's truth that every topological space admits a right topological semigroup structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $(X,\tau)$ be any topological space. For $x,y\in X$ define $f(x,y)=x$ and $g(x,y)=y.$ Then $(X,\tau,f)$ and $(X,\tau,g)$ are topological semigroups.

Comment: Also $f(x,y)=c$, for any fixed element $c\in X$.